# Jquery add class for only one IMG of each LI

Tags: jquery, image, class

I'be been struggling with this one for quite a while even though I'm pretty sure this is something really simple...

I just want to be able to add a class for ONE image on each LI when the user click on that image...

Thanks in advance for the help

```
<ul id="slider-offer">      
    <li class="q_slide" id="q_who">
        <h3>Plutôt famille ou amis?</h3>
        <div class="les_images">
            <img class="img_choice" src="img/questionnaire/famille.jpg" />
            <img class="img_choice" src="img/questionnaire/solo.jpg" /> 
            <img class="img_choice" src="img/questionnaire/couple.jpg" />   
            <img class="img_choice" src="img/questionnaire/amis.jpg" />
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="q_slide" id="q_when">
        <h3>Saison ?</h3>
        <div class="les_images">
            <img class="img_choice" src="img/questionnaire/printemps.jpg" />
            <img class="img_choice" src="img/questionnaire/ete.jpg" />
            <img class="img_choice" src="img/questionnaire/automne.jpg" />
            <img class="img_choice" src="img/questionnaire/hiver.jpg" />
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="q_slide" id="q_where">
        <h3>Ambiance ?</h3>
        <div class="les_images">
            <img class="img_choice" src="img/questionnaire/plage.jpg" />
            <img class="img_choice" src="img/questionnaire/city.jpg" />
            <img class="img_choice" src="img/questionnaire/pleinair.jpg" />
            <img class="img_choice" src="img/questionnaire/sport.jpg" />
        </div>
    </li>   

    <li class="q_slide" id="q_length">
        <h3>Trajet ?</h3>
        <div class="les_images">
            <span class="duree" style="float:left">0 H &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp </span>
            <input  style="width:700px; height:20px;" type="range" name="points" min="0" max="600">
            <span class="duree" style="float:right">6H et +</span>
            <br/><br/><br/>
            <p> heures </p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And now my JQUERY code:

```
$('.img_choice').click(function()
    {
        $('.img_choice').removeClass('img_choice_click');
        $(this).addClass('img_choice_click');
    });
```

Comment: Which ONE? First? Last?

Comment: whats the problem your code looks fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```
$('.img_choice').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('img_choice_click').siblings().removeClass('img_choice_click');
});
```

Comment: You missed the part about adding this class to the parent.  I'm not sure anyone actually read the question.

Comment: I must admit i'm not sure OP wants to add class to the parent or only to the element. As i read the question, its only for clicked image.

Comment: @roasted After rereading it, it is unclear exactly what is expected, but I think a class def needs to go on the li.

Answer (score 1):

To add the class to the parent `li` uses the `parents()` method with a filter specified as `li`.  Currently the class is being added to the `img`.  You will also need to remove the added class before adding it to the parent of the clicked `img`.

```
$('.img_choice').click(function()
{
     $('li.img_choice_click').removeClass('img_choice_click');
     $(this).parents("li").addClass('img_choice_click');
});
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/SYMpQ/
*I only added two images in the example*

Comment: this will remove '.img_choice_click' class independently of each li

Comment: @roasted I assumed this class wouldn't be arbitrarily placed considering how specific it was, but still a good point, I narrowed the selector.

Comment: I mean, as i understand question, OP wants only one image with class by LI, so it could have more than one image with class 'img_choice_click' per page

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.img_choice').click(function() {
    $(this).parent("li").find(".img_choice_click").removeClass("img_choice_click");
    $(this).addClass('img_choice_click');
});
```

This code should delete the .img_choice_click in THIS li and add the new one.

Answer (score 0):

This may be your expecting

```
$('.img_choice').click(function()
    {
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('img_choice_click');
        $(this).addClass('img_choice_click');
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7chQh/1/)